# How can I specify a host of a db for my "docker-compose" command?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using this repo https://github.com/sharetribe/harmony and this command to run a db service:

**docker-compose up db**

My db is located on a remote host and I'm a newbie in docker. In the documentation of this repo this isn't described: what's the way to specify a remote host of a db?

Comment: Isn't this in the YAML file that defines "db"?

Comment: Please try to restate your question. There seems to be a contradiction - you are running the command that the README says to use to start a **local** database server, but you say you have a remote database already. Do you want a remote DB that is already running or want to use a local container with a database (running together with the Harmony container on your local host).

Answer (score 1):

If your database is already running elsewhere **you shouldn't use `docker-compose up db`** command because it will only start a new database container locally. Instead you should edit `DB_HOST=db` string in `docker-compose.yml` and set your database's address instead of `db`. Then run the `api` service using `docker-compose up api`.

Comment: i don't understand - your 1st sentence contradicts with the 2nd one

Comment: @Rattiku, please explain the contradiction because I don't see it.